# Android Bluetooth inputstream unable to read continuously

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have the following android code where I am connecting to a device which is sending me continuous stream of data using Bluetooth. In the following code, after getting some data, I am unable to read any more data even though Bluetooth connection is still established and data is being sent by device.

I start getting the following error
Info: error in stream reader:bt socket closed, read return: -1

```
private void readStreamDataInSeparateThread()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(inputStream != null && isConnected())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int readCount =  inputStream.read(buffer); 
                        System.out.println("Info: ReadCount:"+readCount);
                        if(readCount > 0)
                            byteBuffer.add(buffer,0,readCount);
                        else
                        {   
                            if(time_out_counter >= TIME_OUT)
                            {
                                closeConnection();
                                break;
                            }
                            time_out_counter++;
                            System.err.println("Info: error end of stream reached for stram reader");
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        System.err.println("Info: error in stream reader:"+e.getMessage());
//                      closeConnection();
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){}
                }
                System.out.println("Info: stream stoped reading ");
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

But strange thing is if I keep my device'c (Samsung tab 3 neo) wifi on and connected, then i receive no error.
Also, if i increase the time delay to more than 6 secs then, i don't receive this error for very long time.

Please let me know, if anyone can rootcause the issue or give me some pointers

Comment: I too facing the same issue, have you found the fix??